# Import error using relative import syntax

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a project structured like so:

```
/proj
    main.py
    config/
        __init__.py
        setup.py
    gui/
        __init__.py
        app.py
```

The program is run by calling `python main.py`.

In `main.py` I have `from gui import App`.

In `gui/__init__.py` I have `from .app import App`.

Lastly, in `app.py` I have `from ..config import configure`; this throws a `ValueError` that reads `attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. To resolve this, I can alter the strucure:

```
/proj
    main.py
    proj/
        config/
            __init__.py
            setup.py
        gui/
            __init__.py
            app.py
```

But then I have to change the import statments to include `proj` (i.e. `from proj.gui import App`). Is it possible to use relative imports in the former case with the current structure? If not, how can I import what I need from the `config` subpackage?

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it sounds, you can do :

```
from config import configure
```

in `app.py`, for your former case (current structure), because when you run `python main.py`, it interprets `config` as the next level package, and `..` won't work.

(Btw, I think there is lots of room for Python imports to improve. The current PEP 328 is confusing at best).